# This question is for Biblical Unitarians. If Jesus did not preexist His birth how do you explain Him being credited with creation?

Tags: biblical-unitarian

Starting with John 1:3, "All things came into being by Him, and apart from Him nothing came into being that has come into being." Colossians 1:16, "For by or in Him all things were created, both in the heavens and on earth, visible and invisible, whether thrones or dominions or rulers or authorities--all things have been created by Him and for Him."

Then there is Hebrews 1:10 where Jesus' own Father states, "And Thou, Lord, in the beginning didst lay the foundation of the earth, and the heavens are the works of Thy hands;" The writer of Hebrews is quoting Psalm 102:25, "Of old Thou didst found the earth; And the heavens are the work of Thy hands." This Psalm is the prayer of an afflicted man and at verse 24 the man says, "I say, "O my God, do not take me away in the midst of my days etc."

Finally, Revelation 3:14, "And to the angel of the church in Laodicea write, The Amen the faithful and true Witness, the Beginning of the creation of God, say this;"

In view of these Biblical facts about Jesus Christ before He was actually born please reconcile all of this with Isaiah 44:24, "Thus says the Lord, your Redeemer, and the one who formed you from the womb, I, the Lord, am the maker of all things, Stretching out the heavens BY MYSELF, And spreading out the earth ALL ALONE."

Comment: Unitarians don’t believe logos is the son of God

Comment: @User14 They believe that God the Father is one being and Jesus is the Father's son but he is not divine or God by nature as Trinitarians believe. They believe at John 1:1 the "Logos/Word" is not Jesus but God's creative self-expression, His reason, purposes and plans. Vs2 literally states, "this one," and vs3" All things came into being by/through HIM, Greek "him" is auto. Nothing about "plans, purposes or reason. Even you as a JW make Jesus "a god" which is a person. I also provided other verses to back up John 1:1-3. Btw, at Colossians 1:16 why was the word "other" added in the text?

Comment: So since you know that Unitarians don’t believe logos is the son who became Jesus  why do you think a problem exists for them? Isa 44:24 is yhwh speaking not jesus